# how to make single function here used two time

Tags: node.js

In this code :

```
if (!parms.script) { // no script... load filename
            execscript(parms, function (data){
                var text={'result':'success', 'response':data };
                if(typeof(data)!='object') {
                    try {
                        text.response=JSON.parse(text.response);
                    } catch(e) {
                        text={'result':'success','response':data};
                    }
                }
                responsehttp.end(JSON.stringify(text));

            });
    } else {
        //parameterised input will replace in script
        if(query.paraminput!=undefined) {
            var paraminput=qs.parse(query.paraminput);
            parms=merge_options(parms, paraminput);
        }
        execscript(parms, function (data){
            var text={'result':'success', 'response':data };
            if(typeof(data)!='object') {
                try {
                    text.response=JSON.parse(text.response);
                } catch(e) {
                    text={'result':'success','response':data};
                }
            }
            responsehttp.end(JSON.stringify(text));

        });
    }
```

in execscript callback it is called two times , i want to make a single function for executing both call back in if and else .

how can i achieve this .

i tried making seperate function but responsehttp undefinded error camed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (I suspect) is that you had your common function declared outside the context of your http response handler and, therefore, responsehttp wasn't defined.  Instead create it as a [closure function](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) inside your outer function's scope:

```
function someCallbackYouDontShowInYourQuestion(req, responsehttp) {
  // Declare your callback as a closure inside this function, so it
  // captures responsehttp state
  function callback(data) {
    var text={'result':'success', 'response':data };
    if(typeof(data)!='object') {
      try {
        text.response=JSON.parse(text.response);
      } catch(e) {
        text={'result':'success','response':data};
      }
    }
    responsehttp.end(JSON.stringify(text));

  }

  if (!parms.script) { // no script... load filename
    execscript(parms, callback);
  } else {
    //parameterised input will replace in script
    if(query.paraminput!=undefined) {
      var paraminput=qs.parse(query.paraminput);
      parms=merge_options(parms, paraminput);
    }
    execscript(parms, callback);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
callback = function (data){
            var text={'result':'success', 'response':data };
            if(typeof(data)!='object') {
                try {
                    text.response=JSON.parse(text.response);
                } catch(e) {
                    text={'result':'success','response':data};
                }
            }
            responsehttp.end(JSON.stringify(text));

        }

execscript(parms, callback);
```

Comment: i tried this but giving an error that responsehttp is not defined. why that error camed.